# Create a json object for c3js using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, d3.js, c3.js

I am having trouble creating JSON object to plot a chart using C3JS. I am able to plot the chart using a static JSON but my data is dynamic and my chart has to remain generic so I cannot pass a static JSON. 
The Key values of the JSON are generic, only the values have to be changed.

**My JSON current JSON format looks like this.**

```
[
    {
        "Key": "data1",
        "Metric": "field1",
        "Total": 1
    },
    {
        "Key": "data1",
        "Metric": "field2",
        "Total": 1
    },
    {
        "Key": "data2",
        "Metric": "field1",
        "Total": 1
    },
    {
        "Key": "data2",
        "Metric": "field2",
        "Total": 4
    },
    {
        "Key": "data2",
        "Metric": "field3",
        "Total": 4
    },
    {
        "Key": "data3",
        "Metric": "field1",
        "Total": 1
    },
    {
        "Key": "data3",
        "Metric": "field2",
        "Total": 4
    },
    {
        "Key": "data3",
        "Metric": "field3",
        "Total": 4
    }
]
```

**Here is the chart Code.**

```
var xAxis = ['x','data1','data2','data3'];
var data1 = ['field1', 6, 13, 4];
var data2 = ['field2', 3, 3, 5];
var data3 = ['field3, 21, 22, 4];

var data = [""]




var full = [
    /*['x','data1','data2','data3'],
    ['field1', 6, 13, 4],
    ['field2', 3, 3, 5],
    ['field3, 21, 22, 4]*/
];

full.push(xAxis);
full.push(data1);
full.push(data2);
full.push(data3);

var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        x: 'x',
        columns: full,
        type: 'bar',
    },
    bar: {
        width: {
            ratio: 0.7 // this makes bar width 50% of length between ticks
        }
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'category' // this is needed to load string x value
        }
    },
    bindto: '#chart'
});
```

I need help creating a object so I can feed to the C3JS to plot my Stacked Bar Chart. I have to read the data from my json response and push it into a array which looks like this.

```
var xAxis = ['x','Agency','Direct','Employee Reference']; var data1 = ['Permanent', 6, 13, 4]; var data2 = ['Contract', 3, 3, 5]; var data3
= ['Conract on Hire', 21, 22, 4];
```

Any suggestions to change the way I feed it would be of great help too.
This is my first StackOver post sorry for the ambiguity.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
var data = [
{ 'date': '2015-01-01', 'Dept': null, 'SMV': 3},
{ 'date': '2015-01-02', 'Dept': 1, 'SMV': 4}
];
```

An example dataset looks then like this

```
var data = [
['date', '2015-01-01', 2015-01-02'],
['Dept', null, 1],
['SMV', 3, 4]
];
```

Comment: Hi Muhammad Mohsin Muneer,
I am looking at how to create the dataset in javascript.

Comment: The entire code is available at http://jsbin.com/cerilugevo/edit?html,js,console
Hope this helps!

Comment: Code reference in jsbin is just to pull out data from object and push it into individual array, but what i am stuck with is something different. 
i) Key elments stays in first array. [data1,data2,data3]
II) Now the challenge starts, Its a combination array which looks like 
[field1 , 1,3,1] , [field2 , 2,1,3], [field3 , 3,1,2]